# How do I use regular expression to find statements with upper case letters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to search in my entire Python code base for function definitions (including function name, parameter name and annotation expression) that contains upper case letters. So code like the following should be captured:

Example 1

```
def Foobar(arg1: expression, 
           arg2: expression, 
           *args: expression, 
           **kwargs: expression)->expression:
```

Example 2

```
def foobar(arg1: expression, 
           Arg2: expression, 
           *args: expression, 
           **kwargs: expression)->expression:
```

Since there can be multiple `:` in the statement I think it is probably very hard. How can I do it if we can assume there is no annotation. E.g.,

```
def foobar(arg1, 
           Arg2, 
           *args, 
           **kwargs):
```

Comment: Can you share your current code/efforts? And your expected vs actual output with samples?

Comment: The code fragments are not valid. do you mean "**kwargs" with 2 asterisks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use pylint instead of using regex for this. If you really want to use by yourself, you can use the code below.

```
import re

regex = r"def (?P<func_name_and_args>\w*\(.+?\))"

with open(/path/to/file/, 'r') as test_file:
    lines = test_file.readlines()

    matches = re.finditer(regex, lines, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    for match in matches:
        group = match.group('func_name_and_args')
        if any(char != char.lower() for char in group):
            print(group)
```

You can test it with: https://regex101.com/r/BMniq9/1

Answer (score 1):

A bit rough but this should work:

```
def [^A-Z]*[A-Z]+[^)]*
```